# What difference between passing an instance and a brace-enclosed initializer list to a function?

Tags: c++, syntax

Say I have the following code.

```
class A
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    A(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};

float average(A a)
{
    return (a.x + a.y + a.z) / 3;
}
```

Are there any practical differences between calling the function in these two ways?

```
// a)
average(A(1, 2, 3))

// b)
average({1, 2, 3})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the C++ version you are using.

Copied (and sligthly modified) from [copy elision @ cpprefrence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (so, not an exact quote):

> In C++17 core language specification of `prvalues` and temporaries is fundamentally different from that of the earlier C++ revisions: there is no longer a temporary to copy/move from.

This means that the temporary `A` you visually show in `average(A(1, 2, 3))` is not allowed to be copied or moved since C++17. In fact, there is no temporary. Before C++17, most compilers utilized *copy (and move) elision* (that has been allowed earlier too, but it wasn't mandatory) to the same effect - but you could not portably rely on it.

In C++17, this form of *copy elision* was made mandatory and is since called *Return Value Optimization*, or *RVO* for short. You will also read about *Named* RVO (or *NRVO*), which is similar, but does not follow the same rules. It's a bit more complicated and outside the scope of this answer.

Before C++17, `average(A(1, 2, 3))` could actually mean that a temporary instance of `A` is created and that the *move* or *copy* constructor of the `A` in the function would have to move (or for a non-movable, copy) the resources from that temporary - which is usually cheap, but doesn't have to be - and it could come with side effects.

Some types are neither copyable nor movable. In such cases, the call would not be valid before C++17. In C++17, `delete`d *move* and *copy* constructors does not matter in this case since there is no instance to move or copy from - and the call *is* therefore undoubtedly valid.

When using the brace enclosed initializer list, as you do in this example, not even C++11 is allowed to create (and move) a temporary instance of `A`. The values are passed directly to the constructor in `A(float x, float y, float z)`.

Other that that, I can't spot a difference in your example.